# How to display different information on polybar by clicking on one module?

Tags: 18.04, indicator, i3-wm

I'm using polybar on Ubuntu 18.04 with i3.

I like my polybar to display a lot of information but it takes too much space.
When I use too much workspaces at the same time, the information on my bar goes to the right of the screen. Some of them cannot be seen anymore and I have to close a couple of workspaces to make them appear again.

I would like to know if it was possible for internal modules to display different informations when you click on it.

For example, right now, my network modules shows my local IP address, my internet speed, my upload traffic and my download traffic.

I would like to to only show my IP address by default and then switch to my traffic when I click on it. Then if I click a second time, I would like to see my internet speed and then one more click would show me my IP address again.

This way, instead of showing both of them alongside each other, I can only see one and easily switch to the others, gaining a lot of space on my bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for any internal modules. If you want any such functionality, you need to write your own script that produces that information and use a [script module](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Module:-script).

Note: The date module has this functionality to some extent, but no other module has.

Comment: So, is it possible to create a custom script that uses the internal modules output ? And if yes, how to proceed ?

Comment: While this is technically possible with polybar's `-s` flag, it will probably take less effort to just gather that information yourself.